# How to remove image metadata using wand python

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, metadata, wand

I use wand-py but I can't write into Image.metadata , what shoud I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `Image.strip()` method:

```
with Image(filename='i0.jpg') as img:
    img.strip()
    img.save(filename='i1.jpg')
```

see [more detail in the doc](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.6/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.strip).